# MongoDB Unrecognized expression '$replaceOne'

Tags: mongodb, replace, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to run a query to replace a few pattern in my collection:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  lastImageUrl: {
    "$regex": "kidplus-bucket-eu"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      videos: {
        high: {
          videoUrl: {
            $replaceOne: {
              input: "$lastImageUrl",
              find: "/kidplus-bucket-eu",
              replacement: "/kidplus-bucket-demo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      videos: {
        high: {
          videoUrl: {
            $replaceOne: {
              input: "$lastImageUrl",
              find: "/kidplus-bucket-eu",
              replacement: "/kidplus-bucket-demo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      lastImageUrl: {
        $replaceOne: {
          input: "$lastImageUrl",
          find: "/kidplus-bucket-eu",
          replacement: "/kidplus-bucket-demo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But i'm getting this error: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$replaceOne'
I have tried using $replaceAll instead but im getting the same error...

Does anyone know what's wrong here?
TY!

After searching the internet I have found out that my db is outdated (v4.2.22) and the `replaceOne` command was introduced in v4.4.

Is there any alternative for it so that my query would work?

Comment: Please use version 4.4 or higher as suggested by @Jonatan.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using an older MongoDB version.

### Get current Version

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
db.version()
```

If you are getting 4.2 you will need to update probably to at least 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to execute this "replacement" explicitly, here is one such way of how to do so based on the input you gave:

The strategy I choose to use is split the URL by `/`, iterate over the array and look for a match and change the value if needed.
Finally reconstruct the string back to it's original form.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      lastImageUrl: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $split: [
                  "$lastImageUrl",
                  "/"
                ]
              },
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this",
                      "/kidplus-bucket-eu"
                    ]
                  },
                  "kidplus-bucket-demo",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: "",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$value",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this",
              "else": {
                "$concat": [
                  "$$value",
                  "/",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jMrtSqg7sSa)